# Can i train it to detect my face? or any other people face

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I want to create an application where in I capture images of people within my family and detect who it is. can I use vision API to create cloud database to store different pictures of each family members labelled with their names so that  when I pull a request from the API it scans the images from the database and detects which family member it is rather than just detecting the faces in it. can I train it to do so???

Comment: _can I train it to do so???_ Yes. Question answered

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you guide me on how to do it.

Comment: I've not had any luck figuring out how you can train the google vision API to your own labels.  Seems like the IBM equivalent might be a possibility: http://visual-recognition-demo.mybluemix.net/train

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to train the classifier. More details can be found in this link: [How to train and classify images using Google Cloud Machine Learning and Cloud Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow)