# How can I insert images of new brands or logos and be detected with the LOGO_DETECTION annotation of Google Cloud Vision Api?

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm using Google Cloud Vision API to detect logos of brands or companies, when testing everything works correctly. However, in the application that I am developing I need to upload images or logos of brands that are not so popular ( **new companies, new logos or new brands e** ).

**Example** : it is necessary for a new company to upload logos and images and remain in the google database to be able to scan or upload an image and the  **API REST  I get the name of the  new**  company.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i train it to detect my face? or any other people face](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36752626/can-i-train-it-to-detect-my-face-or-any-other-people-face)

Answer (score 0):

You can't add Logo or upload a Logo in Google Cloud Vision API. When a logo become "popular" for Google, you will find it in detection.

I quote from documentation:

> Logo detection requests detect popular product and corporate logos
>   within an image. The response includes the logo name, an entity ID
>   (that may be referenceable in the Google Knowledge Graph), and the
>   bounding box that surrounds the logo position in the image.
>
> The logo detection feature type is LOGO_DETECTION.

Rif: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/other-features#logos

Answer (score 0):

If you need a logo detection API that lets you instantly activate any brand - known or unknown - check out logograb.com